# MutationObserver on window.opener.document not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, mutation-observers

I'm in a window opened by javascript

```
window.open("/altitudeToolBox.aspx", "_altitudeToolBox", "location=no, menubar=no, status=no, titlebar=no, scrollbars=1, resizable=yes");
```

In this new window, I'm using the [MutationObserver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn254985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to subscribe to changes on the opener window.

```
 MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
 if (MutationObserver) {
   observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, observer) {
   ...
   });
 }

observer.observe(window.opener.document, {
          attributes: true,
        });
```

It works fine on Chrome, but not on IE 11 where I get an exception saying NotFoundError.

The error seems to come from the fact that I'm observing the document on another window. If I observe the current window's document, it's fine. I can't find this behavior documented anywhere.

Is there any way to make this work and is this limitation documented?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if you use the window's Mutation observer:

```
var observer = new window.opener.MutationObserver(function (mutations, observer) {/*..*/});
observer.observe(window.opener.document, {
    attributes: true,
});
```

I'm surprised to hear that it works in Chrome. You can't typically interchangably use the resources of one window in another. For instance things like instanceof checks will fail if you import objects from another window (for example: `window.Array !== window.opener.Array`). I would expect the same to hold true for DOM objects.

Comment: I'm having the same exception as described in the question on the call to the observe method

Comment: Where do you get that Error?

Comment: when I call observer.observe, I get NotFoundError